# Python Matplotlib Plot Hourly Data Saved in Defaultdict Line in File

Tags: python, matplotlib, defaultdict

I have a file that contains a few thousand lines of data that looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'2012021310': 76422, '2012021311': 94188, '2012021323': 139363, '2012021312': 111817, '2012021307': 71316, '2012021306': 82418, '2012021305': 65217, '2012021313': 127002, '2012021314': 141099, '2012021315': 147830, '2012021316': 136330, '2012021317': 122252, '2012021318': 118619, '2012021319': 115763, '2012021322': 137658, '2012021321': 130022, '2012021320': 121393, '2012021309': 69406, '2012021308': 66833}) 
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'2012021408': 139745, '2012021409': 143658, '2012021414': 288286, '2012021418': 31216, '2012021416': 268214, '2012021400': 207878, '2012021401': 269296, '2012021402': 270258, '2012021403': 275882, '2012021404': 232521, '2012021405': 195062, '2012021406': 166669, '2012021407': 142855, '2012021417': 245582, '2012021411': 194360, '2012021413': 262078, '2012021410': 158954, '2012021415': 296457, '2012021412': 237083}) 
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'2012021523': 676350, '2012021522': 670147, '2012021521': 650984, '2012021520': 617401, '2012021501': 170448, '2012021503': 246600, '2012021502': 250013, '2012021505': 363866, '2012021504': 300809, '2012021507': 333080, '2012021506': 370454, '2012021509': 343671, '2012021508': 330452, '2012021512': 549736, '2012021513': 622690, '2012021510': 387871, '2012021511': 456171, '2012021516': 647559, '2012021517': 600969, '2012021514': 692257, '2012021515': 706377, '2012021518': 579669, '2012021519': 587969}) 
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'2012021608': 333986, '2012021609': 344126, '2012021602': 651692, '2012021603': 676458, '2012021600': 664484, '2012021601': 686408, '2012021620': 932692, '2012021621': 1065501, '2012021604': 589033, '2012021605': 465191, '2012021623': 1316907, '2012021606': 389669, '2012021607': 342613, '2012021619': 828190, '2012021618': 617836, '2012021622': 1111334, '2012021611': 467532, '2012021610': 387220, '2012021613': 634585, '2012021612': 560227, '2012021615': 718498, '2012021614': 704008, '2012021617': 606396, '2012021616': 665030})
```

The keys are dates/hours like '2012021310' is "02-13-2012 10am" the values are simply counts of an event that occurred.

I'm have a decent understanding for plotting with matplotlib however I'm not sure how to address the data. Is there an easy way to read in each of these lines and address them in a plot similar to the way I would use csv2rec to read in two columns? Or is there a better way?

edit:

This replaces defaultdict(, with "data ="

```
import fileinput

filein = 'list.txt'

for line in fileinput.input([filein]):
        line = line.replace("defaultdict(<type 'int'>,", "data =")
        line = line.replace(")", " ")
        print line
```

this results in:

```
data = {'2012021310': 76422, '2012021311': 94188, '2012021323': 139363, '2012021312': 111817, '2012021307': 71316, '2012021306': 82418, '2012021305': 65217, '2012021313': 127002, '2012021314': 141099, '2012021315': 147830, '2012021316': 136330, '2012021317': 122252, '2012021318': 118619, '2012021319': 115763, '2012021322': 137658, '2012021321': 130022, '2012021320': 121393, '2012021309': 69406, '2012021308': 66833}  

data = {'2012021408': 139745, '2012021409': 143658, '2012021414': 288286, '2012021418': 31216, '2012021416': 268214, '2012021400': 207878, '2012021401': 269296, '2012021402': 270258, '2012021403': 275882, '2012021404': 232521, '2012021405': 195062, '2012021406': 166669, '2012021407': 142855, '2012021417': 245582, '2012021411': 194360, '2012021413': 262078, '2012021410': 158954, '2012021415': 296457, '2012021412': 237083}  

data = {'2012021523': 676350, '2012021522': 670147, '2012021521': 650984, '2012021520': 617401, '2012021501': 170448, '2012021503': 246600, '2012021502': 250013, '2012021505': 363866, '2012021504': 300809, '2012021507': 333080, '2012021506': 370454, '2012021509': 343671, '2012021508': 330452, '2012021512': 549736, '2012021513': 622690, '2012021510': 387871, '2012021511': 456171, '2012021516': 647559, '2012021517': 600969, '2012021514': 692257, '2012021515': 706377, '2012021518': 579669, '2012021519': 587969}  

data = {'2012021608': 333986, '2012021609': 344126, '2012021602': 651692, '2012021603': 676458, '2012021600': 664484, '2012021601': 686408, '2012021620': 932692, '2012021621': 1065501, '2012021604': 589033, '2012021605': 465191, '2012021623': 1316907, '2012021606': 389669, '2012021607': 342613, '2012021619': 828190, '2012021618': 617836, '2012021622': 1111334, '2012021611': 467532, '2012021610': 387220, '2012021613': 634585, '2012021612': 560227, '2012021615': 718498, '2012021614': 704008, '2012021617': 606396, '2012021616': 665030}
```

I'm still not sure where to go from here

edit:

I've gotten much closer with a hybrid of everyone's suggestions:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec

    filein = 'list.txt'
    output_name = "image.png"
    dicts = []
    line = ""

    for line in fileinput.input([filein]):
            line = line.replace("defaultdict(<type 'int'>,", "data = ")
            line = line.replace(")", "")
            line = line.strip()
            exec(line)
            objects = data.items()
            print objects
```

which returns:

```
[('2012021307', 71316), ('2012021306', 82418), ('2012021305', 65217), ('2012021309', 69406), ('2012021310', 76422), ('2012021311', 94188), ('2012021312', 111817), ('2012021313', 127002), ('2012021314', 141099), ('2012021315', 147830), ('2012021316', 136330), ('2012021317', 122252), ('2012021318', 118619), ('2012021319', 115763), ('2012021308', 66833), ('2012021321', 130022), ('2012021320', 121393), ('2012021323', 139363), ('2012021322', 137658)]
[('2012021408', 139745), ('2012021409', 143658), ('2012021403', 275882), ('2012021418', 31216), ('2012021400', 207878), ('2012021416', 268214), ('2012021402', 270258), ('2012021414', 288286), ('2012021404', 232521), ('2012021405', 195062), ('2012021406', 166669), ('2012021407', 142855), ('2012021417', 245582), ('2012021411', 194360), ('2012021401', 269296), ('2012021413', 262078), ('2012021410', 158954), ('2012021415', 296457), ('2012021412', 237083)]
[('2012021523', 676350), ('2012021522', 670147), ('2012021521', 650984), ('2012021520', 617401), ('2012021501', 170448), ('2012021503', 246600), ('2012021502', 250013), ('2012021505', 363866), ('2012021504', 300809), ('2012021507', 333080), ('2012021506', 370454), ('2012021509', 343671), ('2012021508', 330452), ('2012021512', 549736), ('2012021513', 622690), ('2012021510', 387871), ('2012021511', 456171), ('2012021516', 647559), ('2012021517', 600969), ('2012021514', 692257), ('2012021515', 706377), ('2012021518', 579669), ('2012021519', 587969)]
[('2012021605', 465191), ('2012021608', 333986), ('2012021609', 344126), ('2012021602', 651692), ('2012021603', 676458), ('2012021600', 664484), ('2012021601', 686408), ('2012021606', 389669), ('2012021607', 342613), ('2012021622', 1111334), ('2012021623', 1316907), ('2012021620', 932692), ('2012021621', 1065501), ('2012021619', 828190), ('2012021618', 617836), ('2012021604', 589033), ('2012021611', 467532), ('2012021610', 387220), ('2012021613', 634585), ('2012021612', 560227), ('2012021615', 718498), ('2012021614', 704008), ('2012021617', 606396), ('2012021616', 665030)]
[('2012021605', 465191), ('2012021608', 333986), ('2012021609', 344126), ('2012021602', 651692), ('2012021603', 676458), ('2012021600', 664484), ('2012021601', 686408), ('2012021606', 389669), ('2012021607', 342613), ('2012021622', 1111334), ('2012021623', 1316907), ('2012021620', 932692), ('2012021621', 1065501), ('2012021619', 828190), ('2012021618', 617836), ('2012021604', 589033), ('2012021611', 467532), ('2012021610', 387220), ('2012021613', 634585), ('2012021612', 560227), ('2012021615', 718498), ('2012021614', 704008), ('2012021617', 606396), ('2012021616', 665030)]
```

So I'm definitely closer:

edit:

And further yet I have:

```
import fileinput
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec 

filein = 'list.txt'
output_name = "image.png"
dicts = []
times = []
values = []

line = ""
for line in fileinput.input([filein]):
        line = line.replace("defaultdict(<type 'int'>,", "data = ")
        line = line.replace(")", "")
        line = line.strip()
        exec(line)
        for k in sorted(data.iterkeys()):
                times.append(k)
                values.append(data[k])

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(times, values)
hours = mdates.HourLocator()
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y - %M:%D:%H')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate(bottom=0.2, rotation=90, ha='left')

ax.grid()
plt.savefig(output_name)
```

This gets me to the point where I've generated a plot at least. The issue now is that x access doesn't generate labels properly from the data being input. I believe that this is due to the somewhat unconventional time-stamp. Any last suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the timestamps are probably not being converted into datetime objects properly. Using one of the dates above I would do something like: datetime.datetime.strptime("2012021307", "%Y%m%d%H") in the for loop that appends the values to the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I would find a way to get that output into something more userful if at all possible.If not,  you could replace this

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>,
```

with

```
data =
```

while looping over the lines, using string.replace(), and then use the exec() function to execute the literal code that is in that line.

Comment: ok, I did the replace portion of this, however I'm sure how to do the eval part. Also what about the trailing ) do I need to eliminate that as well?

Comment: I added a line to replace the )'s with blanks, also added the output of the print statement.

Comment: Should use exec(), not eval(). Just use the exec() function on that line, i.e. exec(line). The data dictionary should then be in memory. Convert those keys into datetime objects and plot with plot_date().

Comment: I'm much closer, see my latest edit above, I've got all but the iteration through the items for plotting working.

Comment: I've made one last edit above, I've got the data plotting but the timestamps "k" are not recognized correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dicts = []
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        exec("dicts.append(" + l[l.index('{'):l.index('}')+1] + ")")
```

which should read in all of the `dicts` and store them in the list `dicts`. You could then construct a list of  key and value pairs with:

```
tsvals = []
for d in dicts:
    tsvals.append(d.items())
```

and if you wanted them sorted you could of course sort them once you were done constructing that. I would probably save the key and value pairs once I had them like that. A csv file would probably suffice for that purpose.

The `exec` command should only be used on trusted data, though. It is very insecure, but if you are the one generating the data, or if you trust the person generating the data to give you only good data, then I think that is the best way to do this.

Comment: it's a small amount of data from a small dataset that I generated so I consider it trusted. However the first bit of code you show returns: "with f as open(filename):
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

Comment: Sorry, should be `with open(filename) as f` instead. I will edit.

Comment: The enumerate is also superfluous in this code. I had a different idea for a moment and forgot to remove its artifacts. I will remove it.

Comment: mystr produces: "NameError: name 'mystr' is not defined"

Comment: I've made one last edit above, I've got the data plotting but the timestamps "k" are not recognized correctly.

Comment: The problem with not copying and pasting code... Obviously it should have been `l[...]` and not `mystr[...]`